# Get placeid of a location on infowindow click

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2

Is there a way on how to get the placeID of a location when a user clicks on an infowindow of a marker? I created an application that searches nearby places (ex. hospital). What I want to do is to get the placeid of a certain location by clicking on the infowindow, so that I'll be able to get the details of a certain place. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: is there place id returned in reponse from google places api?

Comment: see this http://www.androidtrainee.com/showing-nearby-places-and-place-details-using-google-places-api-and-google-maps-android-api-v2/   it has a detailed way of parsing nearby place data

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 I tried to follow that code. Kindly check this other post of mine, I really can't get to show the phone numbers of the establishments

Comment: give me link of your other post..

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41207093/getting-the-phone-number-of-nearby-place?noredirect=1#comment69613196_41207093

Answer (score 3):

While adding markers store place id (if any you are getting in json/xml response), in snipet of marker like this,

```
marker.setSnippet(placeId);
```

then on click of infowindow get it from Marker object

```
onInfowindowClick(Marker marker){
int placeId = marker.getSnippet();
//now you can use it to call anyother service call
}
```

But my question is are you getting place Id, because it is not clear from your question

[image]

see the highlighted portion it has it see if you can use it, m not sure, sorry

and if it is ussable, you need to parse the json response to get value of id

Comment: How could I get the placeid from the JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

you must create a Marker like this:

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(40.714224, -73.961452))
                        .title("Title")
                        .snippet("Description")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon)));
                marker.setTag("PlaceId");
```

and then:

```
Marker markerClicked;
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                        // Retrieve the data from the marker.
                        String clickTag = (String) marker.getTag();


                        if (clickTag != null) {
                        // do something
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, marker.getTitle() + " è stato cliccato. Tag: " + clickTag + ".", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            markerClicked= marker;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });

googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                      Double lat= marker.getPosition().latitude; // 40.714224
                      Double longit= marker.getPosition().longitude;  // -73.961452
// and then call this url:
// "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452"
                    }
                });
```

P.s.: `private GoogleMap googleMap;`is a field of Activity and is set like `GoogleMap mMap` that you can find in

```
MapView mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                googleMap = mMap;
                 ...
                 }
```